# How to distinguish a JS-submit from using the back button (onbeforeunload)?

Tags: javascript, forms, form-submit, onsubmit

I am going crazy with the onbeforeunload and form.submit(). You are my last hope for a brilliant idea...

What I have is a form. If the user clicks the back button, this causes a lot of trouble, so window.onbeforeunload shows a warning. Of couse submitting the form shall be allowed, therefore form.onsubmit sets a global variable to tell the onbeforeunload-function to shut up. So far allright.

Sometimes the form must be submitted automatically via JS. And I do not have access to the functions that call the form.submit() - or more exactly - users will create some simple code that may include a form.submit().

The point is that form.submit() does, by specification, not trigger the form's onsubmit event. Therefore trying to send a form via form.submit() regularly tells me to consider closing the page.

So back to my hope: Does anyone have a brilliant idea how to solve this vicious circle?

Thanks a lot
BurninLeo

Comment: Do you have control over the previous page? Is it generated with a `POST` request (or indeed a GET you don't want to resend)? You can  prevent reloads/return visits from history being a problem by sending a 302 redirect to mask the request you don't want to repeat: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: Hi! Actually the script already handles most back button clicks correctly. However sometime there is the popup "do you wanna send the data again". And if the user clicks "no" all he sees is an empty page. In other cases the previous page is shown from the browser cache - the user does some work there and if he clicks "OK" I got to tell him that none of these changes were saved :(

Comment: Post/redirect/get will avoid the "do you want to send data" message - if you send a 302 redirect in response to the POST, then the POST request won't be saved in the browser history. Of course, this means you'll need to redirect to a different page that shows the results of the POST (can be the same URL). I can expand on this in an answer if you'd like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var form = document.getElementById('the-form'),
     sub = form.submit;

form.submit = function(){
    alert('caught submit');
    sub.apply(form);
}

form.submit();
```

Comment: Thanks - I have tried this, however Firefox does not like it calling its own native functions: Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "Illegal operation on WrappedNative prototype object"  nsresult: "0x8057000c (NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_OP_ON_WN_PROTO)"  location: "JS frame :: http://127.0.0.1/ofb/oFb/test1/index.php?i=K4AQKP6R :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 651"  data: no]

Comment: Woa! Phantastic!! Thanks a lot.

Comment: np; adjusted answer with fix.